# IIS maintenance with client IP exceptions

Tags: iis, rewrite, maintenance

I'm have no experience with IIS server, but I will have to perform site update. Is there an easy way to put maintenance page, which will be shown to all clients except ones connected from predefined IP addresses? Usually I've performed similar updates under apache/nginx and it was quite easy to do it with rewrite rules, but I am not able to do it with IIS...

Could anyone give me step by step instructions on how to set it up properly? How should that rule look?

Answer (score 1):

The stock IP restrictions functionality and a custom error page would probably do what you want. Without knowing the version of IIS you're running I can't give you step-by-step instructions.

You'd be looking at blocking all requests and allowing a subset of addresses access.

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, I've made simple "maintenance mode" html document, and put it on highest prioryt above other files served by default by the server (index.html, default.asp etc).